# manifest.xml XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest

I'm a newbie, I use the android sdk on ubuntu and downloaded a few free android apps, when I tried to load them onto the sdk using eclipse, it gives an XML parser error. I am unable to view the source code of the application too.

If I try opening the xml file using a browser, I get

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///home/Downloads/apks/BlueFTP.apk_FILES/AndroidManifest.xml
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Has anyone encountered such a problem? Any solutions please?

Content of manifest.xml

```
  <    ü      >                        4   @   N   Z   x   ž   ²   À   Ô   æ   ô     6  R  p  Œ  ¤  ¶      $  8  b  n  ˆ  œ  ¬  Ê  Ú    &  j  z  ¼  ô  >  J  T  v  ˆ     ¼    l  ~  Ô  *  >  ˆ  Ô  ê    4  H  j  ¤  à  (  l  Â   v e r s i o n N a m e    v e r s i o n C o d e    i c o n    l a b e l    n a m e   
 c o n f i g C h a n g e s    s c r e e n O r i e n t a t i o n    m i m e T y p e    t h e m e    e x p o r t e d    e n a b l e d    v a l u e   
 m i n S d k V e r s i o n    t a r g e t S d k V e r s i o n    s m a l l S c r e e n s   
 n o r m a l S c r e e n s    l a r g e S c r e e n s   
 a n y D e n s i t y    a n d r o i d   * h t t p : / / s c h e m a s . a n d r o i d . c o m / a p k / r e s / a n d r o i d        p a c k a g e    m a n i f e s t    i t . m e d i e v a l . b l u e f t p    2 . 5 0    a p p l i c a t i o n    a c t i v i t y    . A M a i n   
 i n t e n t - f i l t e r    a c t i o n    a n d r o i d . i n t e n t . a c t i o n . M A I N    c a t e g o r y     a n d r o i d . i n t e n t . c a t e g o r y . L A U N C H E R    . A S e n d    a n d r o i d . i n t e n t . c a t e g o r y . D E F A U L T    a n d r o i d . i n t e n t . a c t i o n . S E N D   # a n d r o i d . i n t e n t . a c t i o n . S E N D _ M U L T I P L E    d a t a    * / *    . A C o n t a c t P i c k e r    . A A b o u t   
 . A S e t t i n g s    . B u g s M e s s a g e   * . b l u e t o o t h _ s e r v e r s . o p p _ s e r v e r . N o t i f y M e x O P P   * . b l u e t o o t h _ s e r v e r s . f t p _ s e r v e r . N o t i f y M e x F T P    s e r v i c e   ) . b l u e t o o t h _ s e r v e r s . o p p _ s e r v e r . O P P _ S e r v i c e   ) . b l u e t o o t h _ s e r v e r s . f t p _ s e r v e r . F T P _ S e r v i c e    r e c e i v e r   # . b l u e t o o t h _ s e r v e r s . S e r v i c e s L a u n c h e r   $ a n d r o i d . i n t e n t . a c t i o n . B O O T _ C O M P L E T E D        m e t a - d a t a    A D M O B _ P U B L I S H E R _ I D    a 1 4 a a e 1 d 0 8 3 a 7 1 0    u s e s - s d k    u s e s - p e r m i s s i o n    a n d r o i d . p e r m i s s i o n . I N T E R N E T    a n d r o i d . p e r m i s s i o n . B L U E T O O T H   " a n d r o i d . p e r m i s s i o n . B L U E T O O T H _ A D M I N     a n d r o i d . p e r m i s s i o n . R E A D _ C O N T A C T S   ) a n d r o i d . p e r m i s s i o n . W R I T E _ E X T E R N A L _ S T O R A G E    s u p p o r t s - s c r e e n s     € P        &     $ p„…†l        ÿÿÿÿ       `      ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                  ÿÿÿÿ                    ÿÿÿÿ            L      ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                  ÿÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿÿ  ,  t      ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                  ÿÿÿÿ                       ÿ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extract APKs and load the resulting files into Eclipse to examine an app's source code. This is why the XML file is giving you XML parsing errors - it's not XML; it's the compiled form of XML.

All Android apps consist of human-readable Java source code and text XML documents. When compiled, these files get reduced to computer-readable Java classes and binary XML. These are then compressed into an APK and delivered to devices.

You can not reverse this process without the use of a decompiler, and even with a decompiler you will only get an approximation of the input.

If you want to learn how to program Android apps, may I suggest exploring the sample apps included in the SDK.

Comment: I agree. That's why I was amazed about how he could do it! :-P

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the answers, I am a bit disappointed to hear that I can't view the source code of apps freely downloaded from the net and that I have to stick to the samples only :(

Comment: cache22: Lots of Android developers post their source code publicly on the net. For example there's [ConnectBot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) and [growing-phone-pet](http://code.google.com/p/growing-phone-pet/), and more if you search [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch). It's great way to learn.

Comment: Yes.i got the same problem.i can open the APK java source code using decomipler.but at the same time i couldnt open the manifest and other xml files.is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the APK?

try uncompressing it, and paste the content of the `Manifest.xml` file.

Secondly, where are you getting the errors?
When you run the app in the phone? or in the eclipse? if in eclipse, how did you figure out to create a project out of an APK only? or do you have the full project? if you have the full project, then you might be having the Manifest file as well, so just paste that file's contents here and let us check

Sorry for the outburst of questions, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Yes I do have the apk, the content of the apk is quite strange, with some characters which are not in english. I have the full project and I am loading it in eclipse, I wonder if the manifest.xml is encoded in some font?  Also I assume that the .apk file after decompression is sufficient to load in eclipse, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: correction please - the contents of the manifest.xml is quite strange, not the apk as mentioned above

Comment: edited my post to paste the contents of the file, I tried using the apktool on it, I get more errors on trying to decode

Comment: Man.. this isn't what we expected! o_0

Answer (score -1):

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/875/cpsid_87562.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Link gives 404 error